# Why is adding routes for static files recommended in development?

Tags: django

I have a little project using some static files in my applications and everything works fine.

But in development, it seems recommended to add something like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In my `urls.py`.

But in development (`DEBUG=True`), `runserver` seems able to serve static files even if I don't run collectstatic. So I assume it serves it directly from the `statics` application's subdirectories.

So **why is recommended to add a `static()` call to the `urls.py` file if we can do without it?** Plus `static()` won't work with `DEBUG=False` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

> If you use `django.contrib.staticfiles` as explained above, `runserver`
>   will do this automatically when `DEBUG` is set to `True`. If you don’t
>   have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can still
>   manually serve static files using the
>   `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()` view.

The `static()` helper function adds an url for the `serve()` view to your urlpatterns.

As you can see, static files are only served automatically in the development server if `DEBUG` is set to `True`, *and* `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. If the latter is not the case, using the `static()` helper is the recommended way.